# apache .htaccess - cut a string from url and redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

For some reason google indexed several pages of my website as:

```
http://myapp.com/index.php/this-can-be-enything/1234
```

Now, I want to redirect with apache .htaccess those pages to correct urls:

```
http://myapp.com/this-can-be-enything/1234
```

I've googled and tried many options but with no success.
Any tip will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I've added to my .htaccess file following lines:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*index.php.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php(.*)$ $1$2 [NC,R=301,L]
```

I don't know if this is best solution but works ok for me.

Comment: Thanks. This has solved my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870453/htaccess-rewriterule-trouble

Comment: This redirects the user to root level directory, which is not good if the script is in a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Two Parts of problem

1. To make Google aware that indexed page is moved to some other destination you need to handle that @ apache level and issue 301 ( moved permanently )
2. Handler to handle the cached requested URL to new URL using the #1 handler itself.