# remove index.php from url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect normal pages so that users and bots don't access the *domian.com/**index.php**/pagename* version of the pages.

I am currently using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123971/apache-htaccess-cut-a-string-from-url-and-redirect):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*index.php.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php(.*)$ $1$2 [NC,R=301,L]
```

This however also redirects *domain.com/admin/index.php/variables* which stops me being able to access the admin area.

So, how to redirect *domain.com/index.php/pagename* to *domain.com/pagename* without affecting *domain.com/admin/index.php/variables*

Answer (score 0):

The `RewriteRule` command is pointing any URL with 'index.php' in it to another page. Try changing the second command to:

```
RewriteRule ^(index.php)(.*)$ /$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks kededro. i tried as you suggested but it redirects from *domain.com/index.php/pagename* to *domain.com/index.php*
then i tried
`RewriteRule ^index.php(.*)$ $1$2 [NC,R=301,L]`
and that seemed to work, but i'm a bit worried about your comment about security issue. is the above a security issue?

Comment: As long as your file permissions are set up correctly, you should be good. I was worried that you could possibly redirect into the admin directory, but that should not be an issue because `RewriteRule` is secure. I removed my other comment to match this.