# .htaccess RewriteRule trouble

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am guessing this question has been asked many times, but i could not find one that would perhaps give me what I need.

So.. I can access the scripts by the following url's:

```
http://website.com/index.php/hello/world
http://website.com/hello/world
```

Both go to *index.php* which parses the input (hello/world in this example).

this is my *.htaccess*:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?path=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

However. When the site is accessed like this:

```
http://website.com/index.php/hello/world
```

the *RewriteRule* outputs something similar to *index.php?path=index.php/hello/world*

I want to remove that *index.php* after *path=* in the *RewriteRule*

Comment: I think you php script do the conversion..

Comment: @GabrielSantos the trouble is that $_GET['path'] does not exist if i use the /index.php/hello/world

Comment: Somehow there is a very similar question to my.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123971/apache-htaccess-cut-a-string-from-url-and-redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` file should look like this (notice the new rule that checks if index.php is a part of url):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ index.php?path=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?path=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: you have [L], last rule flag on the first one.. I think thats why it doesn't work

Comment: no that's not. [L] flag stops execution of the following rules, which in this case are useless, because the query is already rewritten to `index.php?path=$1%{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: Okay. How about a RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f to rewrite the url if a file exists, because index.php does exist..

Comment: try to remove the first 2 RewriteConds and see what's happening

Comment: Got it right with [OR], so, rewrite if file OR rewrite if not file OR rewrite if directory OR rewrite if not directory.. That works. Cheers! Code: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?path=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

Comment: please post the full `.htaccess` file so i can update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying answer from [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5128278/666835) to suit this question

The .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect user
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*index.php.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php(.*)$ $1$2 [NC,R=301,L]

# Handle the query to PHP
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?path=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

</IfModule>
```